Simulate the dynamics of a 3D discrete rigid body from "first principles"
The question stems from wanting to implement a rigid body dynamics simulation without resorting to any of the well-known concepts that are commonly used, such as moment of inertia, torque, and angular velocity. I only want to use f=ma on point masses, together with some other notion of force transfer that I haven't identified yet.
Here is my model of the problem. A massless support structure (light blue), with some small heavy spheres (black) embedded. The spheres are precisely embedded in the structure and they are not allowed to move around in it, although they can revolve on themselves; there is no friction between the spheres and the support structure. The structure is only intended as a conceptual device to transmit forces; it delivers external forces such as f to the spheres, and mutual internal forces between spheres, that are responsible for keeping them at constant distances to each other.

The problem
Let's assume that we know each mass m[i], the external force f with its point of application q, and all the state variables in the system, that is, I think, all the positions p[i] and velocities v[i] for each point-like mass. We want to compute all accelerations a[i].
The questions

Is the problem above well-defined?
In other words, is the acceleration a[i] a function of all the other variables mentioned above?
Is this function analytic?


As stated in @CortAmmon's answer, the problem can be resolved as you suggest, provided the correct number of independent rigidity constraints is added to the external forces.
I would not be negative about that idea, as in the mentioned answer, because in some cases, the numerical solution of the constrained equations of motion can be preferred over the integration of the rigid body equation for motion around the center of mass.
Algorithms for numerical integration of the equations of motion in the presence of rigidity constraints have been developed over the years. However, a word of caution is necessary to avoid a naive implementation. In particular, it is important to be aware that evaluating the constraint reaction forces (for example, through the Lagrange multiplier technique) is not enough. If we use them in the numerical integration algorithm, the constraint would be satisfied only within its accuracy. For example, using a symplectic Verlet algorithm, we would get the rigidity constraint satisfied only with a global error proportional to the square of the time step. That is not acceptable in the majority of the cases.
Special algorithms dependent on the integration algorithm have been introduced since the pioneering work by Ciccotti and Ryckaert, as summarized in the review paper G. Ciccotti, and J.-P. Ryckaert. "Molecular dynamics simulation of rigid molecules." Computer Physics Reports 4 (1986): 346-392.
The basic idea behind such algorithms is to satisfy the constraint with the maximum accuracy at each time step, introducing an error in the constraint forces that is not larger than the integration algorithm error. The cited paper provides more details.

Thank you, this is really great information! global error proportional to the square of the time step sounds definitely like a problem in practice, but my goal is to gain a basic understanding of how this kind of thing could work, so it's probably good enough for me. I'll take a look at that paper. Thanks!

@damix911 I suggest you practice the numerical integration of the equations of motion for point-like particles before starting with rigid bodies. You'll find that a global error proportional to the square of the time step may be an excellent result.

You can do it, and it will be well defined.  The key would be adding the constraints for a rigid body: the distances between masses never changes.
That being said, what you are doing is really inventing the exact mathematical problem that leads to things like moments of inertia.  If successful, you will have found a way to simulate something in 1,000 equations that we know how to simulate in 4.
If you are interested in first principles, may I recommend delving into group theory.  Once you understand that the rigid body assumptions define a group E(3), you will see that the system you created can only be the same as the usual set of equations
However, if you toss out the rigid body assumptions, and instead do something like springs between masses, you get into finite element analysis, which is a really strange interesting thing.

Nice answer (+1) I am curious whether modeling using "springs between masses" automatically means that we are modeling a rigid body deep down? Can "springs between masses" be used to model liquid or gas particles where the distances/locations between molecules are not rigid?

@James If you have springs between masses, the object is no longer a rigid body at all.  It is an elastic body, if I had to give it a name.  You can accelerate some masses and it takes a while for that acceleration to propagate to the others.  And this model is indeed used to model liquids and gas particles.  You would want something less rigid than a collection of springs pre-structured, but the pattern of applying forces through a force transmission element would still apply.

This is actually really important for some relatavistic paradoxes.  There are some famous problems, like fitting a ladder in a garage that's too long to fit (if you go fast enough, length contraction lets you fit it in).  Paradoxes arise, and many of them are resolved by the fact that in such relatavistic scenarios, we can no longer treat the ladder as a rigid body.  We have to recognize that it has some extent and cannot transmit force from one side to the other instantaniously.

And, just to drop names, the finite element analysis of a liquid or gas is called computational fluid dynamics.  Although they don't always use a bunch of masses like this (sometimes it's easier to use volumes instead of masses)

Thank you for the helpful information. On a more abstract note, second quantization of QFT is modeled as "springs between masses", does this imply that it is actually modeling an elastic solid?

Thank you for the great answer; it sheds some light on a few things that I had thought about but not in much detail. In the past I tried to make some progress by imposing the constraint that the distances between masses never changes; if I remember correctly this implied that the difference between particle velocity is orthogonal to the difference between particle position, for any pair of particles. But I wasn't able to use it to solve for unknowns, back then. Maybe I'll give it another shot. Thanks!

For instead do something like springs between masses, this is something that definitely I had fun with in the past, and it's very much what inspired me to look into this alternative approach to rigid body dynamics, that I described in this question. I don't quite understand why I can put together something like this (https://codepen.io/dawken/pen/NWZLLmo?editors=0010) in 10 minutes while I have no clue where to start from if I replace the springs with rigid rods or some sort of massless support (see OP). I presume that I don't know/understand force transmission and generation from velocity.

By the way, the simulation with springs tends to a rigid body if the Hooke constant is large, but it becomes really tricky numerically. Bear in mind that I am not a physicist, nor an expert in numerical methods, and the simulation that I linked above is very basic, I am sure it can be greatly improved upon. At the same time, conceptually, I wonder if you could create a spring model and apply a limit operation (symbolically, with pen and paper, not numerically) and derive a rigid body model from the spring one by passing the limit k --> +Infinity.

@damix911 Stiff systems of equations are notoriously difficult to model numerically.  That being said, if you use Hooke's law, with k approaching infinity, you do get rigid body mechanics because for any forces, the displacement of the spring tends to 0.  If the displacement of the string is equal to 0 (the limiting case), then you have rigid body mechanics.
